# NETCore Linux Sudo write regular user writable/owned file

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

So I run this command on Linux from user account named 'x':

```
sudo dotnet App.dll
```

And App.dll does:

```
File.WriteAllText("App.txt", "Text");
```

This file is not write accessible to 'x' or normal users. It's owned by root. How can I write it so it's not a root user file but while running from sudo? I know I can grant access/ownership to a username to the file, but what do I do if I don't know the username's name is 'x'?

> I have very little knowledge of Linux. I'm just writing a simple tool that configures some files. It needs to write some root-owned files but also some user-owned files.

I'm not even sure my question makes sense. I want to write a file without the (locked) icon overlay from sudo app execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more [furious googling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11470/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-user-that-launched-sudo) I found that I can get the User's that invoked sudo `UID` and `GID` by running:

```
env | grep SUDO
```

or via C#:

```
var groupId = int.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUDO_GID"));
var userId = int.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUDO_UID"));
var user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUDO_USER");
```

So I can execute:

```
chgrp GID File.txt
chown UID File.txt
```

or `Process.Start` using `/bin/bash -c "command"`:

```
var command1 = $"chgrp {groupId} Test.txt";
var command2 = $"chown {userId} Test.txt";
```

to give the file to the User that launched `sudo dotnet App.dll`.